# how to add a local android lib to gradle build?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have an android library (source) that I have been using in eclipse and i need to port to android studio. I have the library building as its own project. but now i want to use it in another project (somewhere else on the filesystem).

How can i declare this library project to my other project. I don't want to copy the files over but rather use it in place. so it cant be under the other project dir hierarchy.

Hope it make sense. If you need more info let just ask. possibly i have to add stuff to publish it as an artifact? when i was using maven i would declare it as a module with a file path ....

tried

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'path'
    }
}
```

but to no avail ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may get diff results with diff gradle versions but i've done this on 1.10...

gradle.settings

```
 include '..:youLib'
```

AndroidManifest for your lib...

make sure its minimal and it does not contain "ActivityName" or "launcher" props

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':..:youLib')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare libraries in dependencies section:

E.g.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: so how do i declare an external module on the local filesystem - is what i am asking

Comment: all the docs have the modules in the same project but i need to include code from another project.

Comment: No idea if this possible to add an external module 'just like that'. You need to install this module in local repo for instance or copy the artifact You'd like to add as a dependency to the project structure.

Comment: yeah, it should be possible - you could do it in maven maybe its settings.gradle